Is it possible to seal/patch a dishwasher drain hose?
I have a small hole in a white, ribbed drain hose underneath my dishwasher. It's not from being old - it looks like a mouse chewed through it a bit. It appears to be a pain to replace it, which is what I'd normally do, and I want to fix it asap, so I was wondering if there's something I can use to seal or patch it. Again, I know most will say that it's a cheap part and better to just replace. I get it. I'm looking for other options right now. There's no risk of damaging anything if it doesn't work because the dishwasher flashes an error code when there's too much water under it. Ideas anyone?

There are sealing tapes you could try.  How good they are or if a new hose would be cheaper than tape is unknown.  According to some ads you can tape a boat together and stay dry,  I also have a few loads of the back end product of bulls to sell, if you believe their ads.

A picture would be nice and helpful.

Do you have free access all around the hose at the damaged spot? (Is it in the free part of the hose outside of the machine or somewhere still in the innards?) I would suggest self-vulcanizing rubber tape, that thing is reliable and will outlive you if applied correctly, but you need to pull at it quite hard when winding it around the hose, so you need some space to be able to actually do that.

I'd be wary of putting too much trust in that error code. If it's relying on detecting water somewhere that should be dry, you've already got a problem

The level of pain to replace it is probably equal to the pain of sealing it.

Personally, depending on the size of the hole, I'd consider slathering some silicone caulk over the hole, letting it cure, then strapping a flat piece of hard plastic over it with a hose clamp.  But I'd probably just replace it.

I've had a mouse chew throb a dishwasher drain hose. Replacing it on my Zanussi wasn't hard, but was a bit tedious.
The ridging on the hose makes patching much more difficult than on something smooth. Essentially you have to seal all the way round on one narrow ring, and stay sealed through temperature cycles. I got through a couple of loads with waterproof tape of some sort plus hose clips (all stuff I had lying around), soon adding a tray to catch the odd drip. That was a stopgap because I had to get the hose mail order.
